# Changing multicolum table and centering text

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I'm having trouble implementing multicolumns in LaTex and keeping the text in the right places. Ideally I would like to produce a table like this:

[image]

I cannot get the spacing right on the 'traditional machine learning methods' part. My code currently is this:

```
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{ |c||c|c|c|c|c| }
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{SNN-based methodology (ongoing task)} \\
    \hline
    Data Classes& Young Adults & Older Adults & MCI & Accuracy \% & Total 
accuracy \%\\
    \hline
    Young Adults& ? & ? & ? & ? &  \\
    Older Adults&   ? & ? & ? & ? & ? \\
    MCI&   ? & ? & ? & ? & \\
    \hline    
    \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Traditional Machine Learning Methods} \\
    \hline
    Methods & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{MLP}& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{SVM}& 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{MLP}  \\
    Accuracy \% & ? & ? & ? \\ 
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{SNN-based methodology (PMpercept task)} \\
    \hline
    Data Classes& Young Adults & Older Adults & MCI & Accuracy \% & Total 
accuracy \%\\
    \hline
    Young Adults& ? & ? & ? & ? &  \\
    Older Adults&   ? & ? & ? & ? & ? \\
    MCI&   ? & ? & ? & ? & \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Traditional Machine Learning Methods} \\
    \hline
    Methods & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{MLP}& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{SVM}& 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{MLP}  \\
    Accuracy \% & ? & ? & ? \\ 
    \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{SNN-based methodology (PMconcept task)} \\
    \hline
    Data Classes& Young Adults & Older Adults & MCI & Accuracy \% & Total 
 accuracy \%\\
    \hline
    Young Adults& ? & ? & ? & ? &  \\
    Older Adults&   ? & ? & ? & ? & ? \\
    MCI&   ? & ? & ? & ? & \\
    \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Traditional Machine Learning Methods} \\
    \hline
    Methods & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{MLP}& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{SVM}& 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{MLP}  \\
    Accuracy \% & ? & ? & ? \\ 
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{\label{tab:blah blah}
 \end{table}
```

Which gives me:

[image]

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: As always on this site you are much more likely to get help if you post a full minimal example others can just copy and 9lay with.

Comment: Your code produces severa error messages. One being related to declaring 6 columns but wanting to use 7 (See line `Methods & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{MLP}& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{SVM}& 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{MLP}  \\ `), the other being related to the missing `}`  in the `\caption` command.

Comment: To improve the overall look of your table, you might also want to have a look into the `booktabs` package and its manual.